# MAAB guideline : na_0002: Appropriate implementation of fundamental logical and numerical operations

Tags: matlab, simulink

The MAAB guideline [na_0002: Appropriate implementation offundamental logical and numerical operations][1]. Indicates that logical data type shouldn't be used in numerical operations. Among the rationales listed, we can see Code generation, but i can't understand how using logical data type in numerical operations could affect negatively Code generation, since a cast is done for the logical data type ?

Any help please.

Regards

Comment: Probably because the code generation avoids casting. How would you do `double 4 + logical 1` ? should it be 5? but logical 1 does NOT mean 1... Defining that sum is ambiguous, therefore they just dont do it, they leave it for you.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't add, subtract, multiply or divide numbers by logicals (booleans). It just doesn't make sense.

Should the result of a math operation with a logic operation give a numerical or a logical result, for example - it's ambiguous.

Comment: Thank you James and @Ander Biguri for your responses.
I think that Simulink Embedded coder do support cast for boolean data type for code generation.
And actually, I was just wondering if there is another reason other than avoiding ambiguity.

Thanks